# What is the meaning of superscript $\perp$ for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vector-spaces

If $A$ is a matrix, then the nullspace of $A$, i.e. $null(A)$, is a vector subspace. Then, what is the meaning of superscript inverted $T$, for example $$null(A)^\perp$$

on a vector subspace?

Comment: Usually it's the orthogonal complement.

Comment: It's called the [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement).

Comment: It's also the annihilator, which sometimes reduces to orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It $A^\perp$ means orthogonal complement of $A$, meaning the subspace that consists of all vectors which when dotted with any vector from $A$ produce $0$, that is

$$A^\perp = \left \{ \right. \vec{x} \ | \ \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}=0, \ \ \forall \vec{y} \in A \left.  \right \}$$

More at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement.